# magento webstore stop working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Once again thanks for viewing this post i would like to mention that i am start facing a problem with my multistore magento website one of them is stop workung and i goes blank without error please help me

http://u2rehab.com/

https://u2mobility.com/
when i checked my system log i was getting this notice and i fixed this to but still no change i got 
what problem it may be

Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php'  in /chroot/home/utwomobi/u2mobility.com/html/app/design/frontend/u2mobility/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

i fixed this notice

Comment: Have you checked your server error log ? Fatal errors are not logged in `system.log`

Answer (score 0):

If its a blank page coming then you need to check your sites error log.

Also check var/reports folder for some reports.

Also check log files.

These will give you some pointers.

AT PHP level disable Notices and warnings.